# How can one the cardinality of function space $C(X, Y)$ equipped with uniform topology, where $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $(Y, d)$ a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, function-spaces

How can one the cardinality of function space $C(X, Y)$ equipped with uniform topology, where $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $(Y, d)$ a metric space.

I mean how does the cardinality of $X$ and $(Y, d)$ help in finding the cardinality of function space $C_u(X, Y)$.

Comment: Cardinality of $C(X,Y)$ has nothing to do with the topology you are imposing on it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes i know that. I want to know how will the cardinality of $X$ and $Y$ effect the cardinality of $C(X, Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|C(X,Y)|$ will depend on the combination of the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ and $|X|$ and $|Y|$ as well.

Some examples: if $X$ is $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology and $Y = \Bbb Q$, in the usual metric, then $|C(X,Y)| = \aleph_0$, because only the constant functions from $X$ to $Y$ are continuous. We also have the trivial bound $|C(X,Y)| \ge |Y|$ because we always have those constant functions in the set of continuous functions.

If $X=\Bbb R$ in the discrete topology (indeed Tychonoff) and $Y$ is any metric space, then *all* $f: X \to Y$ are continuous, so $|C(X,Y)| = |Y|^{|X|}$ so when $Y=\Bbb Q$  this equals $\aleph_0^\mathfrak{c} = 2^\mathfrak{c}$, e.g.

So the size can differ quite dramatically, and has to be considered on a case by case basis.

Comment: @HennoBrndsma But then how can we calculate the character of $C(X, Y)$ in terms of character of $X $ and $Y$?

Comment: @MirAaliya that will also depend on the topology we put on the function space and we might need more than just the characters of $X$ and $Y$. $\chi(Y)=\aleph_0$ of course, being metrisable matters more than its character.